# Copy mutliple line in vim until empty line

Tags: vim

I would like to yank some lines beginning from 'some_code_to_copy' until the empty line and then do the same for 'some_other_cody_to_copy' in vim.

```
some_code_to_copy(){
   statement;
   statement;
   statement;
   statement;
}

some_other_code_to_copy(){
   other_statement;
   other_statement;
}
```

I could first count the lines of each function and then do `6yy` for the first one and `4yy` for the second one.

I could also use `v` to select the first function and then `y` to yank it. and repeat this for each function.

What I actually want is to navigate to the first line and then tell vim copy all lines until the empty line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `yip` (which means "yank inner paragraph"). `ip` is a motion just like `hjkl` and `$`, `^`, etc., so you can also use it for other things like `dip` do delete the paragraph, `cip` to change it, `gcip` to comment it out if you have the vim-commentator plugin, etc.